# error at gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY

Tags: python, numpy

When i try to apply this code, i get a problem at line six.
can anyone tell me where is the problem exaclty?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('20170616_173327.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_c, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9)
color = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 250, 250)

cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(color, color, mask=edges)

cv2.imwrite("result.png", cartoon)
cv2.waitkey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to the guidelines for asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. make sure that your issue is reproducible for anyone trying to help you. And please also post the full traceback of the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Colours library, for some reason I had to redownload and call all functions again, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, writing

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

instead of gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) solwed my problem.

Comment: i did as you said but i still get an error:

"
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-xeqjxthj\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'


Process finished with exit code 1

"

Comment: Looks like the image did not load

Comment: Try to give full path : like img = cv2.imread(r'C:\User\....jpg',0)